# Windows Authentication Between IIS Servers

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, iis

I am looking for a solution where I can "forward" the same user Windows credentials from one IIS server to another.

Can this work, if in server 1 IIS is configured with URL Rewrite to work as reverse proxy to server 2? On server 2 I have a WebAPI application running under IIS.

**The servers** and user's current Windows login on their machine **are in same domain**. (However there is no domain setup I know of, probably to login happens to the server machine that is running the application)

Comment: are the two servers on the same domain?

Comment: Yes @user1666620, same domain.